# Question about exact sequences and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, exact-sequence

I am having much trouble trying to understand the idea of an exact sequence.  As a toy example, I'm looking at the following exact sequence:

$$0 \xrightarrow{} ker(T) \xrightarrow{\iota} V \xrightarrow{T} U,$$

where $T$ is a homomorphism from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $U$, and $\iota$ is the natural inclusion map from the kernel of $T$ to $V$.  I know this is a very vague request, but in short I was simply hoping for somebody to explain to me exactly **what the heck is going on here**.  For some reason I am getting in my mind the thought that $ker(T) = 0$, meaning that $ker(\iota) = ran(\iota) = 0$, but I've been thinking about this so much to the point where the harder I think the more I find myself confused.  Thanks in advance.

(**Motivation**: Besides simply trying to understand this stuff, I am also wanting to prove that given any homomorphism $S: W \xrightarrow{} V$ with $T \circ S = 0$, there exists a unique homomorphism $F: W \xrightarrow{} ker(T)$ such that $S = \iota \circ F$.  Now, this seems to make sense intuitively, but I think I am having difficulty proving this because I am not using everything known about the exact sequence above.)

Comment: What is your question? Do you know the definition of exact sequence? The sequence is called exact if $\ker g= \operatorname{im} f$.

Comment: Well, I am just trying to get a feel for what is going on.  For instance, one question I have is what does the first part of the sequence, $0 \xrightarrow{} ker(T)$ that is, tell us about $ker(T)$?  Am I right in believing that $ker(T) = 0$?

Comment: No. You can not state that it is zero. If you have $0\to X \to Y$ you can say that the map $X\to Y$ is injective since its kernel is equal to the image of the previous map (which is zero). Also if you have $X\to Y\to 0$ then you can say that the map $X\to Y$ is onto since the kernel of the last map is the whole $Y$ (because it is the zero map).

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider a countable family  $\mathcal F=\{A_i\}_{i=1,2,3,\dots}$ of vector spaces over a fixed ground field $\mathbb k$, let us say $\mathbb k=\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ for simplicity. With $0$ we denote the vector space with only one element, i.e. the unit of the abelian group composition (the "zero vector"). The following

$$A_1\stackrel{\alpha_1}{\rightarrow} A_2 \stackrel{\alpha_2}{\rightarrow} A_3 \stackrel{\alpha_3}{\rightarrow} \cdots$$

is called sequence of vector spaces, with $\alpha_i\in \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb k(A_i,A_{i+1})$. The sequence is said to be exact if 
$$\operatorname{ker}(\alpha_i)=\operatorname{im}(\alpha_{i-1})$$
for all $i\geq 2$.

This condition is easy/hard to prove, given the above. The easier part is to show that $\alpha_{i+1}\circ\alpha_{i}=0$, i.e. $\operatorname{im}(\alpha_i) \subset \operatorname{ker}(\alpha_{i+1})$; to prove that 
$\operatorname{ker}(\alpha_{i+1}) \subset \operatorname{im}(\alpha_i) $ one needs to work on an existential condition on certain elements.

- **Short exact sequences**

Take $\mathcal F=\{0,A_2,A_3,A_4,0\}$; the exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow A_2 \stackrel{\alpha_2}{\rightarrow} A_3 \stackrel{\alpha_3}{\rightarrow} A_4 \rightarrow 0$$
is said to be a short exact sequence: by exactness we have $\operatorname{ker}(\alpha_2)=0$ **and** $\operatorname{im}(\alpha_3)=A_4$.

In other words, if the above sequence is short exact, then

$$0\rightarrow A_2 \stackrel{\alpha_2}{\rightarrow} A_3 $$
is exact, i.e. $\operatorname{ker}(\alpha_2)=0$,
or  $\alpha_2$ is a monomorphism (=it is injective). This sub-sequence is said to be left exact. Moreover
$$ A_3 \stackrel{\alpha_3}{\rightarrow} A_4 \rightarrow 0$$
is exact as well: $\operatorname{im}(\alpha_3)=A_4$,
i.e. $\alpha_3$ is an epimorphism (=it is surjective). This sub-sequence is said to be right exact.

Morally speaking, if a short exact sequence exists for $A_2$, $A_3$ and $A_4$, we can say that $A_3$ is "composed" in some  way from $A_2$ and $A_4$, like in a twisted composition of those vector spaces. Split short exact sequences clarify the concept of twist, but I won't talk about them now.

- **On the Toy example in the OP**

Using the above definitions, let us consider the toy example

$$0 \xrightarrow{} ker(T) \xrightarrow{\iota} V \xrightarrow{T} U,$$

where $T$ is a homomorphism from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $U$, and $\iota$ is the natural inclusion map from the kernel of $T$ to $V$. This is an exact sequence; in fact, although $\operatorname{im}(\iota)=\operatorname{ker}(T)$ and $\operatorname{ker}(\iota)=0$ by construction.

Question in the OP: what does it happen if $T$ is injective, i.e. $\operatorname{ker}(T)=0$? If this is the case, then you can introduce the left exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow V \xrightarrow{T} U; $$

exactness is equivalent to injectivity of $T$.
Similar considerations hold if $T$ is surjective. If $T$ is an isomorphism, then

$$0\rightarrow  V \xrightarrow{T} U\rightarrow 0 $$

is a short exact sequence.